# How to get data from checked checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get data of the particular checkbox that I click and make that data go away if I uncheck it but clicking All I want all the data of the table to be displayed.

I don't want to use JQuery and want to use JavaScript. I tried doing as the code below but could not achieve the result I was expecting.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("All")[0];
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0];
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function firstFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("select-one")[0];
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text-one")[0];
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function secondFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("select-two")[0];
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text-two")[0];
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="All" onclick="myFunction()">All
<input type="checkbox" class="select-one" onclick="firstFunction()">Select 1
<input type="checkbox" class="select-two" onclick="secondFunction()">Select 2
<table class="text" style="display:none">
  <tr>
    <td>Checkbox is CHECKED!</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-one" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 1!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-two" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 2!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I expect my output to display all of the values when clicked All and only particular values when a particular checkbox is clicked.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("[class*=text]") ...loop through each node and change css "style.display"  for all not  just first

Comment: Your `<table>` has a `display:none`, so even if you make the `<td>` visible in `firstFunction()` or `secondFunction()`, your `<table>` (which is the parent container), is still hidden.

Comment: Can we use JQuery? As you know that Jquery will work faster and have short code?

Comment: We can use JQuery but I wanted to focus on JS to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
function myFunction(chk) {
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('.text tr td');
  if(chk.classList.value.includes('All')){
    if(chk.checked){
      all.forEach(function(td){
        td.style.display = "block";
      });
    }
    else{
      all.forEach(function(td){
        td.style.display = "none";
      });
    }
  }
  if(chk.classList.value.includes('select-one')){
    document.querySelector('.All').checked = false;
    all.forEach(function(td){
      td.style.display = "none";
    });
    if(chk.checked){
      document.querySelector('.text-one').style.display = "block";
    }
    if(document.querySelector('.select-two').checked){
      document.querySelector('.text-two').style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  if(chk.classList.value.includes('select-two')){
    document.querySelector('.All').checked = false;
    all.forEach(function(td){
      td.style.display = "none";
    });
    if(chk.checked){
      document.querySelector('.text-two').style.display = "block";
    }
    if(document.querySelector('.select-one').checked){
      document.querySelector('.text-one').style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="All" onclick="myFunction(this)">All
<input type="checkbox" class="select-one" onclick="myFunction(this)">Select 1
<input type="checkbox" class="select-two" onclick="myFunction(this)">Select 2
<table class="text">
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-one" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 1!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-two" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 2!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've touched up the JavaScript and HTML a tiny bit as below:

The main difference is having first, second and third variables in a global scope.
Plus, moving the class="text" into the first TD.

Also, initailize(); which grabs the three HTML elements sort of thing.

JavaScript:

```
var  first = ''
,    second = ''
,    third = '';

function initialize () {

    first = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0];
    second = document.getElementsByClassName('text-one')[0];
    third = document.getElementsByClassName('text-two')[0];
}

function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("All")[0];
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        first.style.display = "block";
        second.style.display = "block";
        third.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        first.style.display = "none";
        second.style.display = "none";
        third.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function firstFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("select-one")[0];
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    second.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    second.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function secondFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("select-two")[0];
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    third.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    third.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<body onload="initialize();">
    <input type="checkbox" class="All" onclick="myFunction()">All
    <input type="checkbox" class="select-one" onclick="firstFunction()">Select 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="select-two" onclick="secondFunction()">Select 2
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-one" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 1!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-two" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 2!</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Hope this helps,

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Just to specifically point out what was your issue:

Your `<table>` has a `display: none` style that is not updated from `firstFunciton()` or `secondFunction()`. So, even though you make the `<td>` visible, the parent (`<table>`) is still hidden, so the child rows or cells of the table will not show.

There are more elegant solutions, but to keep the code closest to what you have, you could update your HTML table to this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-one" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 1!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-two" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 2!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And your Javsacript function `myFunction()` to this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("All")[0];
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0];
  var first = document.getElementsByClassName("text-one")[0];
  var second = document.getElementsByClassName("text-two")[0];
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
    first.style.display = "block";
    second.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
    first.style.display = "none";
    second.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: @AnushaNeupane, could you please clarify what is the expected behaviour then?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using pure javascript like this

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("All");
var myFunction = function() {
var at = this.getAttribute("id");
if(at == 'selectAll' ) {
var checkedele = classname[0].checked;
var closestTr = classname[0].closest("td").closest("tr");
    closestTr.getElementsByClassName('togg')[0].style.display=checkedele?'block':'none';
  for (var i = 1; i < classname.length; i++) {
            classname[i].checked = checkedele;
           var closestTr = classname[i].closest("td").closest("tr");
           closestTr.getElementsByClassName('togg')[0].style.display= checkedele?'block':'none';
  }
} else {
var checkedele = this.checked;
var closestTr = this.closest("td").closest("tr");
         closestTr.getElementsByClassName('togg')[0].style.display= checkedele?'block':'none';
}

var checkedCount = 0
for (var i = 1; i < classname.length; i++) {
if(classname[i].checked){
 checkedCount++; 
 }
}

if(!checkedCount) {
classname[0].checked = false
var closestTr = classname[0].closest("td").closest("tr");
    closestTr.getElementsByClassName('togg')[0].style.display='none';
}
};


 for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
   classname[i].onclick = myFunction;
 }
```

html code

```
<table class="text">
  <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="All" id="selectAll">All</td>
<td class="togg" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="select-one All">Select 1</td>
   <td class="togg" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 1!</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="select-two All">Select 2</td>
   <td class="togg" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 2!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/gfz1vyr2/1/

you can optimise this code...

Answer (score 0):

check below code if works as per your requirement:

```js
function myFunction(t) {

 var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text-all")[0];
      if(t.checked)
      { 
       text.style.display = "block";
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("chk");
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
       checkboxes[i].checked = true;
          CheckFunction(checkboxes[i]);
     }
      }
      else
      { 
       text.style.display = "none";
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("chk");
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
       if(checkboxes[i].checked)
           { checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            CheckFunction(checkboxes[i]);
             }
     }
      }
}

function CheckFunction(chk)
{
 if(chk.id == "chk-one")
  {
    var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text-one")[0];
    if (chk.checked == true) {
      text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      unchkAll(text);
    }
  }
  else
  {
   var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text-two")[0];
    if (chk.checked == true) {
      text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      unchkAll(text);
    }
  }
}

function unchkAll(text)
{
text.style.display = "none";
      var chkall = document.getElementById("chk-all");
      if(chkall.checked)
      {
       chkall.checked = false;
       myFunction(chkall);
      }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chk-all" class="All" onclick="myFunction(this)">All
<input type="checkbox" id="chk-one" name="chk" class="select-one" onclick="CheckFunction(this)">Select 1
<input type="checkbox" id="chk-two" name="chk" class="select-two" onclick="CheckFunction(this)">Select 2
<table class="text">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-all" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-one" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 1!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-two" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED 2!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.